# Put HTML representation as a class property in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is more a question about best practices and reasons for *not* taking a certain approach.  My idea is that I'm building this model called Badges and I want to have a standardized display pattern for all of them.  It seems like storing that pattern in the model class itself makes sense, but I haven't really seen that done.  Is this a bad idea and if so, why?

Basic example:

```
class Badge(models.Model):

    badge_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    @property
    def as_html(self):
        html = """
                <div>
                    {name}
                </div>
                """.format(name=self.badge_name)
```

Then in the django template could just call `{{badge.as_html}}`.

Comment: Probably better making a widget

Comment: That seems very messy having multi-line HTML floating in between model definitions.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative might be to use inclusion tags as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) in the documentation.  This would allow you to put your template/html in a separate file like this:

```
<!--- badges.html -->

<ul>
    {% for badge in badges %}
        <li> {{ badge }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Where I've defined `show_badges` something like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()    

@register.inclusion_tag('badges.html')
def show_badges(user):
    badges = user.badges.all()
    return {'badges':badges}
```

Then on my main template page I can use the template snippet above with:

```
{% show_badges user %}
```

Comment: The link to the documentation is dead. The updated one should probably be https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags